# In Cadence AWR, why do the theoretical values for components yield much lower results than the optimized values?

Tags: rf, filter, simulation, band-pass, cadence

I used Cadence AWR Design Environment to simulate a bandpass filter from 1.6 GHz to 3.2 Ghz, in both Pi and T formats.

I calculated the theoretical values for each component and put them in the schematic. Granted, there was a little inaccuracy in the return loss (S (1,1)) plot. My band should come under the -10dB line, but some part of the band didn't.

So I used the Optimization tool present in the AWR software itself. Now the values of my components changed far too much. I did get the intended result, but I am wondering if my calculations were way off, or that the AWR software included a lot of intrinsic parameters of the components in its calculations that yielded such different values from mine.

For reference, here is a sample plot of the return loss plot, before and after optimization.

[image]

Comment: What did the AWR support team tell you when you contacted them?

Answer (score 1):

I got this info from my professor. He says it is due to consideration of parasitic effects of various components at higher frequencies that my simulation results were way off from my theoretical calculations. Had I included all or most of those effects into my calculations, I would also get almost the same result as my simulation yielded.